# Java code formatting in intellij Idea (chained method calls)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I have a small problem with java code formatting in Intellij Idea 14.1.4.
I have a piece of code formatted manually by me, that looks good for me:

```
public class Test {
    private static final ImmutableMap<String, String> map = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>()
            .put("key", "value")
            .put("key", "value")
            .put("key", "value")
            .put("key", "value")
            .put("key", "value")
            .put("key", "value")
            .build()
}
```

but when I reformatted this code(Ctrl + Alt + L), I got:

```
public class Test {
    private static final ImmutableMap<String, String> map =
            new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>().put("key", "value")
                    .put("key", "value")
                    .put("key", "value")
                    .put("key", "value")
                    .put("key", "value")
                    .put("key", "value")
                    .build()
}
```

**Expected result:** Intellij won't reformat anything because the code is already well-formatted.

I have a scheme with the next settings:

[image]

**Could anybody explain how I can reach expected result?**

Comment: I tried you code in 14.1.3 But it is not recreated.

Comment: Have you tried to format your code with "Align with multiline" checked?

Comment: version 14.1.4.  what groups I need to chose "Align with multiline" for?

Comment: try "chained method calls"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I ticked property

> "keep when reformatting"/"Line breaks"

it helps to format code on my own, with custom line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

There is another one option called "Wrap first call" in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 (I'm not sure when they exactly added it):

[image: Wrap first call option]